# Non-solvable, closed subgroups of $\mathrm{PSL}(2,\mathbb{R})$

Tags: lie-groups, topological-groups, solvable-groups

It is mentioned [here](http://books.google.dk/books?id=hahgP78rnTUC&pg=PA18&lpg=PA18&dq=non-solvable+subgroup+of+PSL%282,R%29+discrete&source=bl&ots=mcrt0BV2g0&sig=4cz3lNJd8EWEPwypnEqsEMtaMZU&hl=da&sa=X&ei=b6ACU-yEKs3csgaq_YHACw&ved=0CDgQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=non-solvable%20subgroup%20of%20PSL%282%2CR%29%20discrete&f=false) that non-solvable closed subgroups of $\mathrm{PSL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ are either the entire space or discrete. My question is this: Is there any easy proof of this, or do any of you have a great reference with a proof? I have next to no knowledge on Lie groups at all, but I do need the result to prove that non-solvable subgroups of $\mathrm{PSL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ are Powers groups (in an operator algebra context).